# When C++ uses gdb to debug, how to directly enter the function？

Tags: c++, gdb, gem5

I am using gdb to debug gem5 (an emulator written in c++). This simulator is very code-intensive and uses a lot of complex structures.
When I used vscode, I found that I couldn't jump to the definition of the function very well (the project is very large, there are many, many functions with the same name, and there are many codes written in special languages, which are automatically translated into c++).

I am using gdb to debug it. I found an uncomfortable debugging problem.

For example the following statement. I want to go into the `initialAcc` function.
When I use gdb to debug, the breakpoint is set at this location.

```
 this->fault = this->staticInst->initiateAcc(this, A(),B());
```

When I use `s` to try to step into the function, it goes into `operator->` function, then into the `A` function, then into the `B` function. Finally enter the initiateAcc function.

This is causing me a big problem.
For example, when I enter the `A` or `B` function, if I use `n` in the last sentence, the initialAcc function will be executed directly, and the next statement will be reached, so that I cannot enter the initialAcc function. If I keep using `s`, I may encounter a very long chain of calls.
In the end I didn't even know where I was going.

Setting a breakpoint directly on the statement at the beginning of initialAcc is a good choice, but since Vscode shows missing references, I can't find where the `initialAcc` function is, which is why I use gdb. There are many functions that are automatically translated into C++ using some scripts. And I always have similar problems.
Is there a general way for me to directly enter this `initiateAcc` function?

Thanks!

Comment: Try [`advance initiateAcc`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/Continuing-and-Stepping.html#index-advance-location).

Comment: Thanks! But shows this sentence: Function "initiateAcc" not defined.

Comment: `Finally enter the initiateAcc function.` then note the location and set a breakpoint there, and the next time you will continue to that breakpoint.

Comment: I thought about this approach, but it's not what I want. The project is huge, it involves inheritance of many classes, and sometimes the call chain is so long that it's impossible for me to remember all the locations. It is impossible for me to debug once and record a location.